# Facing output parsing errors, while trying to visualize using python agent and sql agent

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

In context with a question answered here, [Data Visualization with Langchain create_sql_agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879308/data-visualization-with-langchain-create-sql-agent).

While trying to visualize an output of sql agent using python agent, I'm facing the following error.
"handle_parsing_errors=True.UserWarning: Received additional kwargs {'handle_parsing_errors': True} which are no longer supported. warnings.warn() "

I tried adding the following in my agent,

config={"callbacks":[ConsoleCallbackHandler()]},handle_parsing_error=True

```
 agent = initialze_agent(
        tools=[
            Tool(
                name="PythonAgent",
                func=python_agent.run,
                description="""Useful to run python commands""",
            ),
            Tool(
                name="SQLAgent",
                func=sql_agent.run,
                description="""Useful to manipulate databases """,
            ),
        ],
        llm=model,
        agent_type="zero-shot-react-description",
        verbose=True,
        **config={"callbacks":[ConsoleCallbackHandler()]},
        handle_parsing_error=True**
    )
```

The suggested way to correct the code was to add handle_parsing_error=True. However the error still persists.

```
agent.invoke({"input":"find the number of employees in each department and plot a graph for it"})
```

ValueError: An output parsing error occurred. In order to pass this error back to the agent and have it try again, pass handle_parsing_errors=True to the AgentExecutor. This is the error: Could not parse LLM output: `I don't know The above is the error before adding handle_parsing_error=True.

Comment: The error says that `handle_parsing_error` is no longer supported. Did you have another error before adding this? Please include it in your question.

Comment: Also, please provide [mre]

Comment: Please don't comment the updates to your question. [edit] it to include the code and the error.

Comment: hey @Arjit how did you fix this?